# Magento version in backend different from Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento, upgrade

I have a problem with my Magento version. I have updated Magento from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.4, then for incompatibility with an extension, I re-established a backup with Plesk.

Now in the backend, the version is 1.9.1.0 but in the Magento Connect Manager I can't update because it says the version is already 1.9.2.4.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not exhibit anything related to code. Since it's a configuration based question (using Magento Connect) I suggest it be moved to the [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It's ok! at the suggestion of robbie I have already posted on magento.stackexchange.com .Regards